# Android: how to capture network packet in rndis initialization phase?

Tags: android, networking

Try connecting android rndis tethering with windows PC. Windows ip address is 169.254.x.x until one mintue later, dhcp negotiation again and ip turns into 192.168.x.x.

Debugging with android output, I saw tethering service and dnsmasq was launched. dnsmasq received dhcp discover in one minute. The expected behavior should be dhcp right afer tethering.

Used tcpdump, however it stops when adapter existance changes. If I try it again, missing network packet during init phase.

Tried wireshark/network monitor on windows side, I have to bind with an adapter. Still missing network packet for init phase.

Any tool(android or windows) to capture network log during adapter early phase? I saw WindowsCE netlog dumps all data since it's based on ndis. For ethernet NIC, I could try a hub and network monitor P-mode, but hub not works for usb rndis.

By the way, I discussed with qualcomm usb engineer. From usb driver, there's no error for debugging. Apprecaite for other debugging idea.

Thanks,
-Johnny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

windows etl can dump out component trace and network traffic. Specific to my dhcp issue, use "netsh dhcpclient trace dump" to get dhcp log if client is win7. netfilter might be helpful to collect linux side traffic.